# react table how to reduce white space in columns

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Hi I have a react table...which displays some numeric data I cant seem to figure out how to reduce white spaces in columns..things I have tried.

I have overridden

```
getTheadThProps, getTdProps with 

    const tightStyle = () => {
      return {
        style : {
          paddingTop : '0px',
          paddingBottom : '0px',
          paddingLeft:'0px',
          paddingRight:'0px',
          fontSize: 'x-small',
          padding: '0',
          margin: '0'
        }
      }
    }
```

Also overriden getProps in column with

```
const tightCell = (state, rowInfo, column) => {
      return { style : {color : 'red', fontWeight : 'bold', padding : '0', margin :  '0'}}
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code that actually renders your table.

Comment: Hi Ryan C here is an example 

https://codepen.io/AmitChopra123/pen/ZVJRop?editors=1111

what I would like to have is very little to no white space around text in columns. Changing width property seems to have strange results.

Answer (score 0):

react-table has a default column min-width of 100px. You need to override this setting.

```
import { ReactTableDefaults } from "react-table";
var columnSettings = {
  ...ReactTableDefaults.column,
  minWidth: 20
};
...
 <ReactTable
    column={columnSettings}
```

Full example on CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit 318p0vj19m]